# What is this part called?

Tags: maintenance, nissan, replace, repair, windshield-wipers

So in the beginning ONE of my windshield wipers just went absolutely dead (could move it easily with my hands) and I took it to the shop and the guy removed what he called ''arms'' but when I went to another dealer to purchase the part, he told me it's called a 'bracket'. Now when I youtube ''how to change windshield bracket'' I can't find anything and if I search for ''windshield arm'' they just take the wiper themselves off and not the underlying thingy that I purchased.

It's 2 metal rods which connect to the wipers, bridging the motor and the wipers I think. What is this part really called and can you link a video showing how to replace it if you can find one? (my car is Nissan Almera '98).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The piece I believe you are talking about the linkage. Many times the bushings will wear out and the linkage will pop off of the arm or motor. Here's a drawing which depicts a typical linkage connection:

[image: windshield wiper linkages]

EDIT: I just noticed in this picture, it looks as though the **Right Hand Link** attaches at the wiper arm ... it really doesn't. It fits on the ball which is on the wiper arm pivot (not named).

EDIT2: And I'm asleep today. [This site](http://www.justanswer.com/nissan/1pxrn-install-windshield-wiper-motor-1998-nissan.html) may/may not help in your replacement.

Answer (score 0):

These combined linkages are called the windshield wiper TRANSMISSION. There are bushings in the linking arms that sometimes wear out or get rotten and disintegrate. Sometimes these can be purchased separately and be replaced. Other times a whole new transmission will have to be purchased. If it's an old model vehicle and parts are no longer available you may have to search a salvage yard (which may also present the same worn out condition) or a restoration parts company. If not you'll have to probably improvise your own bushing. You can search "windshield wiper linkage bushings" or just "rubber bushings" to begin finding results. If you're referring to the part of the arm that splines to the oscillating shaft (which is a less common failure) you have to pull back a locking clip in order to remove the old arm and then the new arm spring tension must be overcome to simply align the splines with the splined shaft with the arm at the right angle and push it on. If the shaft splines are also stripped then the whole wiper transmission will need to be replaced as I don't think the shaft and it's bracket are sold separately! A salvage yard is often a good solution then.